# How to save custom object for Eclipse Natures Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am working on an Eclipse plugin with a custom project nature. I need to save some custom information about my project into workspace. For example, my project have to use several db connections information, which places in `List<DbConfig>`. The following is DbConfig class:

```
public class DbConfig {
    private String dbName;
    private String connectionString;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    //... getters and setters
}
```

I need somethink like that, but want to put into preferences Object type:

```
IProject project =  ... get project from selection or something
IScopeContext context = new ProjectScope(project);
Preferences projectPreferences = context.getNode("your nature id");
projectPreferences.put(key, value);
projectPreferences.flush();
```

In which the object should I place this List and some other preferences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store objects in the preference store.

You can save any data you like in the 'state location' for your plugin.

Get the state location using:

```
Bundle bundle = ... your plugin bundle

IPath path = Platform.getStateLocation(bundle);
```

The returned `IPath` value will be in the workspace metadata area.

You could use a separate file for each project.

You can get your `Bundle` using:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```

or

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("your plugin id");
```

Comment: Hi, Greg! You as always helping me, thanks.
When I should call it? In CustomProjectNatures class?

Comment: You use this in the same place that you were going to use the preferences

Comment: I still not understand. How I can get from bundle my prefernces like in example?

Comment: I am saying you don't use preferences for this. You use files in the state location. It is up to you to read and write these files and to provide a system to access them.

Comment: When I get `path` I can separate projects just add project name segment into `path`?. But what happens if I rename or move a project?

Comment: The path you get is a directory. I would use a file in this directory for each project. You will have to manage renames/moves (perhaps using a rename participant)